# Jax-ws client spring xml bean configuration to java based configuration?

Tags: java, spring, jax-ws, spring-java-config

Can you help me convert following spring xml based configuration to java based configuration of beans?

```
<jaxws:client id="helloClient"
                  serviceClass="demo.spring.HelloWorld"
                  address="http://localhost:9002/HelloWorld" />
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to declare a bean in any of your configuration classes with the properties you have in your question. 
It should look something like this:

```
@Bean(name = "helloClient") // this is the id
public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
    String address = "http://localhost:9002/HelloWorld";
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factoryBean = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setServiceClass(HelloWorld.class);
    factoryBean.setAddress(address);

    return (HelloWorld) factoryBean.create();
}
```

Your method will return an object of the Service class.
You need a Jax proxy factory bean to set the properties and then create the client (cast it to your service class) and return it.